# Add an ID to div within javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add an ID to the div listed in this javascript code:

```
if ( $target.find('.parallax-inner-' + this.settings.id).length < 1 ) {
                $('<div></div>')
                    .addClass('gambit_parallax_inner')
                    .addClass('parallax-inner-' + this.settings.id)
                    .addClass( this.settings.direction )
                    .prependTo( $target );
            }
```

I tried adding:

```
.attr('id', 'ID-NAME')
```

To the string with the .addClass section. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Where have you added it?

Comment: I added it just before the first .addClass('gambit...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you added the `.attr('id', 'ID-NAME')`, but this would work:

```
if ( $target.find('.parallax-inner-' + this.settings.id).length < 1 ) {
  $('<div></div>', {
    "id": "ID-NAME"
  })
  .addClass('gambit_parallax_inner')
  .addClass('parallax-inner-' + this.settings.id)
  .addClass( this.settings.direction )
  .prependTo( $target );
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... Just tried this but it's still not adding the ID when I load the page on my website. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the below code working fine.

```
$('<div></div>').attr('id','ID-NAME').addClass('gambit_parallax_inner').addClass('parallax-inner-' + this.settings.id).addClass(this.settings.direction).prependTo( $target );
```

Check in the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ThetHlaing10/gzLa46cg/).

I think the error coming from other portion of your code.

Answer (score 0):

All you need:

```
$('<div />', {
   id        : 'ID-NAME',
   class     : 'gambit_parallax_inner parallax-inner-'+ this.settings.id +' '+  this.settings.direction,
   prependTo : $target
});
```